# PHP warning message in Zen Drupal sub-theme

Tags: drupal, drupal-zen

When using a Zen sub-theme in Drupal, I get the following warnings.  How can I resolve them?

```
Warning: in_array() [function.in-array]: Wrong datatype for second argument in zen_preprocess_html() (line 111 of sites/all/themes/zen/template.php).
Warning: in_array() [function.in-array]: Wrong datatype for second argument in zen_preprocess_html() (line 112 of sites/all/themes/zen/template.php).
Warning: in_array() [function.in-array]: Wrong datatype for second argument in zen_preprocess_html() (line 113 of sites/all/themes/zen/template.php).
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the sub-theme's .info file, add these lines:

```
settings[zen_html5_respond_meta][] = respond
settings[zen_html5_respond_meta][] = html5
settings[zen_html5_respond_meta][] = meta
```

I found this workaround at http://drupal.org/node/1357538.